# Loop query with different value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `schedules` that contains `sched_id, sc_id1, sc_id2, sc_id3, sc_id4, sc_id5, sc_id6, sc_id7, sc_id8, sc_id9, sc_id10, sched_name`.

I have also table `subject_current` that has `sc_id, sl_id, schoolyear, semister, etc...` `sc_id1 - scid10` is a "foreign key" from `sc_id` of table `subject_current`

Also, I have a table `subject_list` with `sl_id, subject_code, subject_description, subject_prereq`. `sl_id` from table `subject_current` is a "foreign key" from `sl_id` of `table` `subject_list`.

Now, what I want to do is to "echo" the `subject_description` from table `subject_list` only giving me the value of `sc_id1 - sc_id10` from table `schedules`.

This code doesn't work:

```
for($jaa = 1;$jaa < 11;$jaa++){
    $s_scid = "s_scid".$jaa;
    $s_sublist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_current WHERE sc_id='$s_scid'");
    while($rows_ss = mysql_fetch_assoc($s_sublist)){
        $ss_slid = $rows_ss['sl_id'];

        $ssl_sublist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_list WHERE sl_id='$ss_slid'");
        while($rows_ssl = mysql_fetch_assoc($ssl_sublist)){
            $ssl_slid = $rows_ssl['sl_id'];
            $ssl_subdesc = $rows_ssl['subject_description'];
        }
    }
    echo $ssl_subdesc;
}
```

**EDIT**

This is what I want to exactly happen:

```
$s_scid1 = $rows_s['sc_id1']; // which is a value of 1
$s_scid2 = $rows_s['sc_id2']; // which is a value of 2

$s_sublist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_current WHERE sc_id='$s_scid1'");
while($rows_ss = mysql_fetch_assoc($s_sublist)){
    $ss_slid1 = $rows_ss['sl_id'];

    $ssl_sublist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_list WHERE sl_id='$ss_slid1'");
    while($rows_ssl = mysql_fetch_assoc($ssl_sublist)){
        $ssl_slid1 = $rows_ssl['sl_id'];
        $ssl_subdesc1 = $rows_ssl['subject_description'];
        echo $ssl_subdesc1;
    }
}
$s_sublist2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_current WHERE sc_id='$s_scid2'");
while($rows_ss2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($s_sublist2)){
    $ss_slid2 = $rows_ss2['sl_id'];

    $ssl_sublist2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_list WHERE sl_id='$ss_slid2'");
    while($rows_ssl2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($ssl_sublist2)){
        $ssl_slid2 = $rows_ssl2['sl_id'];
        $ssl_subdesc2 = $rows_ssl2['subject_description'];
        echo $ssl_subdesc2;
    }
}
```

This is a pain to write it 10 times. So I want to loop it. But someone told me it's bad and told me about `INNER JOIN`. But how can I with `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Why dont you use inner join and fetch the records instead of calling query multiple times?

Comment: what do you mean by "the code don't work"? do you get an error or unexpected results? be more specific please.

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of this line? Looks strange to me. `$s_scid = "$"."s_scid".$jaa;`

Comment: @Ashalynd, oopppssss!!! Typo error, updated my question. Don't work as in it doesn't echo anything but no error prompting.

Comment: @almasshaikh, how to use that sir?

Comment: This is not good. A database table is not a spreadsheet. See normalization.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it, you should do something like:

```
for($jaa = 1;$jaa < 11;$jaa++){
    $s_scid = "s_scid".$jaa;
    $the_query = "SELECT sl_id, subject_description FROM subject_list sl JOIN subject_current sc ON sl.sl_id=sc.$s_scid";
    /* the above should generate a JOIN with a particular element from your master table */
    $ssl_sublist = mysql_query($the_query);
    while($rows_ssl = mysql_fetch_assoc($ssl_sublist)){
        $ssl_slid = $rows_ssl['sl_id'];
        $ssl_subdesc = $rows_ssl['subject_description'];
        echo $ssl_subdesc;
    }
}
```